# Event ID Errors 9335 and 9331 after removing exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, public-folders

I had 3 exchange servers in my environment. We migrated everything from the exch 2007 server to a new exchange 2010 server. No problems or errors during migratation. So now I have just two Exchange 2010 servers running sp3

After uninstalling the Exchange 2007 server I get the following errors on only 1 of my exchange servers

Event ID 9335, MSExchangeSA

OABGen encountered error 80004005 while cleaning the offline address list public folders under /o=Heartspring/cn=addrlists/cn=oabs/cn=Default Offline Address List.  Please make sure the public folder database is mounted and replicas exist of the offline address list folders.  No offline address lists have been generated.  Please check the event log for more information. 
- \Default Offline Address List

Event 9331, MSExchangeSA

OABGen encountered error 80004005 (internal ID 501038d) accessing the public folder database while generating the offline address list for address list '/'. 
- \Heartspring

This seems to be only occurring on the new exchange 2010 server. The first one I put in is not throwing any errors. After some research I thought the problem would be replication in the public folders. I looked at all my public folders and I have everything replicating to first exchange 2010 server. I do not have anything replicating to the new exchange 2010 server. From my reading Exchange 2010 doesn't use the public folders and uses web distribution so I did not setup replication to the secondary 2010 server. Could this be my problem?

Also I am only running Exchange 2010 and 2013 clients. So I found an article saying that I could disable distribution of the offline address book via the public folders. However, this did not seem to make a difference in the errors.

Any suggestions of what to try next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have read isn't strictly true. In a clean installation, rather than an upgrade then Public Folders are not enabled by default and therefore web distribution would be used. However in a migration a lot of settings will come across from the previous installation. Never presume anything.

You should check the OAB distribution that you have enabled. If Public Folders is enabled then you should really have that replicated to all of the servers with public folders on them.

If you haven't enabled public folder distribution then that will not be the issue.

I would also check the OAB generation server is set correctly.

If you still have public folders, ensure that there is a public folder database set on each database - it doesn't always set it automatically.

Comment: I think you may have suggested what I needed. My OAB generation server was set as the new exchange 2010 server while my public folder database and replication is on the other server. I moved the generation server to the old 2010 server and will monitor and see if that fixes it. Thanks

Comment: Well, changing the generation server did nothing but move my error from one exchange server to the other. I checked my OAB distribution and I only have web-based enabled. As I said I tried changing the generation server to match my public folder replications. That just moved my error from one server to the other. I checked that there is a default public folder database set for each database and there is. I did notice the default OAB is set to blank. I thought about setting this but I would think if that was the problem both servers would be throwing the errors.

Comment: I would set the default OAB on the databases to begin with. 
I would also try creating a new OAB and replacing the one you have.

Comment: Creating a new Offline Address book fixed my problem. Thanks